# PostgreSQL: How to access the new value generated by a serial type column, in an insert command?

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I would like to access the newly created records ID(PM) in the insert command.

I have a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE item_list."groups" (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar NOT NULL,
    hierarchical_id varchar NOT NULL,
    parent_id int4 NOT NULL
)
```

When I insert to the table, a new value for the **id** is generated automatically, because of the **serial** type.

However, I would like to fill the hierarchical_id so its the **concatenation of the groups parents hierarchical_id + the newly created groups id**.

EG.:

- The parents hierarchical id is: 0-12
- I insert a new group, which gets 20 for it's id.
- The new groups hierarchical_id should be 0-12-20.

**Can I do this in the same query? If so, how should the insert command look like, to access the newly generated id?**

The parents hieararchical_id is known, it doesnt need to be queried.

Comment: `currval()` or `lastval()`

Comment: What if the id's suddenly jump to 1653 or 284748 ? Would that be an issue? Some failed INSERTs or some roque process touching the sequence could these jumps.

Comment: How can i reference the sequence behind the serial type with currval() or lastval()?

Comment: The jump wouldnt be a problem, if the value in both ids is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is probably a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ident_trig() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   NEW.hierarchical_id := concat(NEW.hierarchical_id, '-', NEW.id);
   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER ident_trig BEFORE INSERT ON item_list."groups"
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION ident_trig();
```

Then you insert the parent's `hierarchical_id`, and the trigger will modify it correctly.